# Extracting `X` from `Rand StdGen X`

Tags: haskell

Working on Homework 12 of Prof. Yorgey's UPenn [class](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/12-monads.pdf) from 2013, it presents the `Battlefield` data type.

```
type Army = Int

data Battlefield = Battlefield { attackers :: Army, defenders :: Army } deriving Show
```

For the second homework question, it asks to implement the `random` and `randomR` functions.

```
    -- @author: Brent Yorgey
    first :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
    first f (a, c) = (f a, c)

instance Random Battlefield where
    random = first (\(as, ds) -> Battlefield as ds) . twoInts
    randomR = undefined -- TODO
```

I implemented the above `random` using the following functions.

```
randomBF :: Rand StdGen Battlefield
randomBF = getRandom

twoInts :: RandomGen g => g -> ((Army, Army), g)
twoInts gen = let (one, gen')  = random gen
                  (two, gen'') = random gen'
              in ((abs one, abs two), gen'')
```

I'm curious how I can get a `Battlefield` from `randomBF`.

I tried the following:

```
ghci> evalRandT randomBF (mkStdGen 5)
Identity (Battlefield {attackers = 7777369639206507645, defenders = 5955775402155530247})
```

However it's wrapped in an `Identity`. I'm not sure what that is. But, how can I extract the `Battlefield ...` part in idiomatic Haskell?

Comment: You've had your literal question answered, but I am still a bit confused: Using `randomBF = getRandom` to implement the `Random` instance seems circular to me, because used that way, `getRandom` is actually calling out to the instance you are trying to define! In fact as far as I can see the code you have listed is a perfectly good instance definition if you just remove the `randomBF` declaration altogether.

Comment: but, is it necessary to give type information, i.e. the part after `::` in `getRandom :: Rand StdGen Battlefield`? In other words, is using `randomBF` useful since it's more concise than the former?

Comment: It could certainly be useful to define `randomBF` as a shortcut to use in GHCi, where type hints are often missing. In a whole program, though, type inference would usually take care of choosing the right type.

Comment: Thanks, @ØrjanJohansen. With respect to `getRandom :: (MonadRandom m, Random a) => m a`, I don't understand how `getRandom` type checks to return a `Rand StdGen Battlefield` in `randomBF`. Why does it?

Comment: It's because there is a predefined `MonadRandom (Rand StdGen)` instance as well as the `Random BattleField` instance you've defined, so `m = Rand StdGen` and `a = BattleField` are allowable substitutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the value from the Identity monad, use `runIdentity` from  `Data.Functor.Identity`.

You could also use: `evalRand randomBF (mkStdGen 5)` which returns a Battlefield value.

Comment: Your answer indicates to me that my `evalRandT` approach is idiomatic. Is that so?

Comment: I believe that's in `Data.Functor.Identity`, not `Data.Functor`.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I can say two things: 1) I've never had to use the Rand monad over anything other than the Identity monad in which case it is simpler just to use `evalRand`; 2) there is a performance penalty for using transformer stacks.

Comment: @user5402, doesn't that typically depend on inlining? Some things should also be a little better for `Identity` in base 4.8: `fmap = coerce`, `foldMap = coerce`, `foldl = coerce`, `foldl' = coerce`, `(<*>) = coerce`.